# unrar nested folder in ubuntu strange behaviour

Tags: command-line, rar

I have some folders and files, I created a rar file from them and copy them to my linux machine using ftp then I use this command line to extract them:

```
sudo unrar e files.rar /home/usr1/file
```

It start working but after I open the folder, I did not find my folders, I only find files a lot of them but not structured in folders like the original folder.

How can I unrar them with keeping the original structures of files and folders?

Comment: Why the F are you using `sudo`? You shouldn't get used to using `sudo` everywhere, only for commands that really need it, and if you do, only if you understand how and why the command may trash your machine.

Comment: darn it I missed that. @GuntramBlohm is correct. NEVER use sudo when not needed. andrew: still don't want it? 7 upvotes already :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unrar) says:

```
e - Extract files to current directory.
x - Extract files with full path.
```

so it is expected behavior.  Use `x` for to have it restore including path names.